# how to retrieve data from dATABASEb in a binary tree

Tags: php, tree, binary-tree

I have a `database` where `one sponsor id` has `2 user` then `these 2` has another `two.

It means 4 and so on like `2,4,8,16,32`.
How do I `show` them in a `table`,which loop should I use in php
to show `2,4,8,16` linked with each other here is my `Database`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 for( $i = 2 ; $i <=32 ; $i++ )
    {
         echo $i." ";
        $i += $i-1;
    }
```

you can also use

```
for( $i = 2 ; $i <=32 ; $i+=$i )
{
     echo $i." ";
}
```

Thank you..